# implementing cache on filter apis spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, spring-data-redis

I am working on a spring boot app where I have multiple fetch apis which are basically filter apis taking in params and sending response from db.

Now under load they are acting pretty slow,Is there any way I can fasten these with cache?

Can filter apis results be cached? as they may have different filters everytime.

Currently I did this:

```
@Cacheable(value = "sku-info-cache", unless = "#result == null")
public SkuGroupPagedResponseMap fetchSkuGroupsByDatesAndWarehouseId(Integer warehouseId,
                                                                    Integer pageNumber,
                                                                    Integer pageSize,
                                                                    String startDate,
                                                                    String endDate){
    log.info("fetching from db");
    SkuGroupPagedResponseMap skuGroupPagedResponseMap = locationInventoryClientService.fetchSkuGroupsByDatesAndWarehouseId(warehouseId,pageNumber,pageSize,startDate,endDate);
    updateLotDetailsInSkuGroup(skuGroupPagedResponseMap);
    return skuGroupPagedResponseMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this particular scenario is using a smart key. As per your case, you can make a smart key using the combination of requested filter parameters which will lead to formation of 5! combination of keys (in your case) which can be updated at time of database update using prefix deletion strategy of cache update and hence proves to be very fast. I have tried this and found to be very fast.